# What does it mean that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 - x + 15)$ has class number 3?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I found on the internet that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 - x + 15)$ has class number **3** (e.g. [here](https://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/2.0.59.1)).  Could someone show me a prime number that factors in three different ways?  Or how to generate the answer by computer, possibly with [SAGE](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/tour_numtheory.html)?

I am sure there are quick answers if I knew more number theory, it's at least *implied* that we can do this result more explicitly. Maybe we need to compute the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$ first, the discriminant is $D = (-1)^2 - 4 \times 1 \times 15 = -59$ so the ring of integers should be $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-59}]$ which looks possibly correct.

---

The technical definition of [class group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group#Properties) is less intresting to me than numerical examples. Yet here's my guess:

The definition of the ideal class group is defined as follows (e.g. in these [notes](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Elior/teaching/1617/538_W17/538_notes.pdf)):
$$ \frac{J_K}{P_K} = \frac{\text{fractional ideals}}{\text{principal fractional ideals}} $$
This is the quotient of two abelian groups, we're saying the quotient group is $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

We seem to be measuring the text to which the multiplicative group $\big(\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 - x + 15)\big)^\times$ can be written as the ratio of two elements n $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-59}]$.

---

The textbook [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group#Properties) of class number is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ and the factorization $6 = 2 \times 3 = (1 + \sqrt{-5})\times (1 - \sqrt{-5}) $ so the ideal $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$ is *not* [principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain).  So the class number is **two**.

Also $9 = 3 \times 3 = (2 + \sqrt{-5}) \times (2 - \sqrt{-5})$ and that $(3, 2 + \sqrt{-5})$ is not principal.

$\mathbb{Z}[i] = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1)$ is in fact a [UFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain).

Comment: Look up "class number" in general. It is not about factoring in three different ways.

Comment: Did you want `/` after $\mathbb Q[x]$?

Comment: It means the ideal class group of fractional ideals has order $3$.  Wheb the class number is equal to $1$, the ring of integers is a P.I.D.

Comment: The class number is not about factoring - it is a [certain quotient group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group). The usual trick for computing it for quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ with negative discriminant is to compute the reduced binary quardratic forms of the same discriminant. In the example $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ you give you can say the class number is at least 1, and then compute [Minkowski's Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_bound) to conclude

Comment: the 2 non-principal ideal classes are given by the ideals $(3,(1+\sqrt{-59})/2)$ and $(3,(1-\sqrt{-59})/2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your field is $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{-59}]$ and the ring of integers is slightly larger than $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-59}]$: it is $R = \Bbb Z[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-59}}2]$.

Let's write $a$ for $\frac{1 + \sqrt{-59}}2$, so that $a^2 - a + 15 = 0$.

Consider the ideal $(3, a)$ of the ring $R$. An easy calculation shows that

> $(3, a)^2 = (9, 3a, a - 15) = (9, a + 3)$;
>
> $(3, a)(9, a + 3) = (27, 3a + 9, 9a, 4a - 15) = (a + 3)$.

Thus we have $(3, a)^3 = (a + 3)$ is a principal ideal.

Now let's show that $(3, a)$ itself is not principal.

If $(3, a) = (c)$ for some $c\in R$, then we have $3\in cR$ and $a \in cR$. Taking norm gives $N(c)\mid N(3) = 9$ and $N(c) \mid N(a) = 15$, so we must have $N(c) = 1$ or $3$.

But $N(c) = 3$ is not possible: if we write $c = u + av$ with $u, v\in \Bbb Z$, then the norm $N(c)$ is equal to $u^2 - uv + 15v^2$. It is easy to show that this cannot be equal to $3$ for any pair of integers $u, v$.

Thus $N(c) = 1$, so $c$ is a unit and we get $(3, a) = (1)$. We then get $(a + 3) = (3, a)^3 = (1)$, contradicting the fact that $N(a + 3) \neq 1$.

Comment: No, $(3, a)^2 = (9, a+3)$, not $(3, \overline{a})$.  The cube is $(a + 3)$, not $(3)$.  The norms don't match in your equations.

Comment: @RaviFernando I corrected my answer. I don't see any problem with the norms.

Comment: Excellent, +1.  I may not have expressed myself correctly about the norms:  I meant to say that your ideal equations previously stated that the ideal $(3, a)$, of norm 3, has a square of norm 3 and a cube of norm 9 (instead of 9 and 27).  It's all correct now.

Comment: Although I would add that you can see that $(3, a) = (c)$ implies $N(c) = 3$ directly, because the norm of an element equals the norm (i.e. index) of the ideal it generates.

Comment: Does the fact that the $3^{rd}$ power of $(3,a)$ is principal correspond to the class number being $3$?  Would the $2^{nd}$ power of $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ be principal?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, the square of $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$ in the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is principal. The third power of $(3, a)$ being principal means that the class group contains a $3$-torsion element, and hence the class number is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation, @WhatsUp; $+1$